# How to track button click in salesforce using javascript

Tags: javascript, frontend, salesforce, backend, salesforce-commerce-cloud

I am new to salesforce and javascript.
I have a button on a page and want to record the button if it gets clicked on the page to the customer profile as a boolean.

I have a button with an id="example-button".

I have a function in a scripthelper.js file that goes like function

```
function addedToCart(){
  var addedToCart = customer.getProfile.getCustom().buttonAdded; //Gets the custom attribute from the Business Manager
  var buttonClicked = document.getElementById("example-button");//grabbing button element
  if(buttonClicked)// this is where I dont know the condtional 
    addedToCart  == true;
  }
}
```

I don't know what to add in the if statement to check if the button was clicked so the custom attribute can be set to true. I know I am using front end with the get element by ID, so if there another or easier way to do this please let me know!

If the button is clicked I want the attribute to be set to true

Comment: Your code just detects the existence of the button. You need to set an event listener to that button, either using standard JavaScript or by adding some functionality in the salesforce admin console

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a tracking event on the targetted button:

```
$('#example-button').on('click', function (e) {

});
```

Check this for future reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events